# Trying to reap the benefits of the Rich WEB.UI.Gridview control in a C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I know that I can't use this web control in my C# windows application and that I am restricted to DataGridView control. But this does not display results in an elegant manner as the Web.UI.Webcontrol.GridView control but instead displays it like the results when a SQL query is executed in sql server.

I prefer not going down the path of hosting a webuser control which in turn would launch my website using the Web.UI.WebConntrol.GridView control.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the DataGrids look a lot nicer than the default, [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164098.aspx) explains some methods you can use, mostly by changing the available properties, and making use of the DataGridTableStyle and DataGridColumnStyle.

If you want to implement paging, and are working with a read only dataset, you can look at this [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305271).

Finally, if you've got money to spnd, there are many companies selling a version of a datagrid control that will look more like the web control, [Syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/) and [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/index.xml) are just two, although I've not used them myself, so can't say how good they are